# How to pull file name from URL and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have built a custom document library in SharePoint using CSS and HTML and I need a script that will show the opened file name in the ribbon above the library. I have very little Javascript experience so I could use a little help. Here's the library

[image: http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/4132/folderpic3.png]

So as you can see I need the name of the folder I open to be displayed in the gray ribbon. I have the web part to do it I just dont know the correct javascript. The file URL will be something like.

```
http://sharepoint/sites/Jarrod/DurangoTest/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FJarrod%2FDurangoTest%2FShared%20Documents%2FTest1&FolderCTID=0x01200094D5A58A4F099E49BE1A8BA2F7DE9E0D&View={653454F3-1CE4-48C1-967C-5BA6023D349E}
```

Comment: We need a little more information to do that. Where is your folder information stored and what do you expect to be shown in the ribbon with that URL? Test1?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses the Information will be stored on a sharepoint portal I dont have the exact location yet, this is in my Sandbox right now, and yes I am wanting Test1 to show in the ribbon.For now Id like to use the URL I posted at the bottom. I should be able to fill the script in when I move the Library from my sandbox to the actual site.

Comment: This is the same as a newer question that you recently posted, [Pull a Specific File name from URL with JavaScript/Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749273/pull-a-specific-file-name-from-url-with-javascript-jquery), which has answers and is a more specific question.