# Pull a Specific File name from URL with JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to pull a specific file name from a URL, Ive looked at the posts but there isnt anything that answers the question that I need. I need a Javascript or Jquery that can pull just the file name ("Test1") from:

```
http://sharepoint/sites/Jarrod/DurangoTest/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FJarrod%2FDurangoTest%2FShared%20Documents%2FTest1&FolderCTID=0x01200094D5A58A4F099E49BE1A8BA2F7DE9E0D&View={653454F3-1CE4-48C1-967C-5BA6023D349E}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question you asked 1 week ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can get url information like that from the `window.location` object. Try this out

```
params = window.location.search.split(/&/)

for (var i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
  if (params[i].match(/^\??RootFolder=/)){
    paths = params[i].split(/\//);
    filename = paths[paths.length-1];
    break;
  }
};
```

Comment: That will get you everything after the last `/` character.  The URL provided also includes a querystring, so additional parsing will be required to remove that portion and get just the file name.

Comment: Yeah, I think I misread what he was looking for... I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan is on the right track.  It looks like you're looking to parse a value from the querystring rather than find the name of the requested file.  You'll first need to get the value from the querystring.  You can use `window.location.search` to get the full querystring from the URL.  Then parse the querystring to find the value you want.  Here's a little JS function that does that:

```
// parses the query string provided and returns the value
function GetQueryVariable(query, name) {
    if (query.indexOf("?") == 0) { query = query.substr(1); }
    var pairs = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == name) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

*Then* you're ready to parse the value using Jonathan's suggestion to get the name of the file.  You might have to do some unescaping (using the JS method `unescape`) to convert the value from the querystring into the "real" value that can be parsed more easily.